# Determine in English a UIColor

Tags: objective-c

I have used an extension to get the average color.
For example:

```
UIColor *color = self.imageView.image.averageColor;

(lldb) po color
UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.956863 0.117647 0.0980392 1
```

I am looking for a way to determine in English a UIColor for example "Red" above for all colors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no such facility available.  You'll need a DIY option.

Comment: Can you convert HEX to English? Thanks?